# Display nested lists on Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I need to display a list of A objects (think `List<A>`). A has the following structure:

```
class A {
    List<B> bList;
    List<C> cList;
}
```

All three lists can be of arbitrary length. `bList` and `cList` should be displayed in their entire length in each row of the list of As. Each list is backed by a SQLite cursor. It's a sort of calendar view. The following image illustrates the idea:

[image]

Now, I'm wondering what's the best way to achieve this "in the Android way". I tried multiple things:

1. ListView for A with nested ListViews for B and C: Not recommended, hard to disable the scrolling behaviour of B and C.
2. ListView for A with LinearLayout for B and C and programmatically adding child views to the LinearLayouts in the Adapter: I have to manage Cursor updates for B and C and adjust the height of the rows myself, lots of view management code in the Adapter where it does not belong.
3. Composing everything of nested LinearLayouts: Same problem as 2, even more Cursors to deal with.

Maybe there's a different way where I can fully take advantage of existing functionality?

I already had a look at similar questions on StackOverflow. The top two suggestions seem to be:

- Spread data over multiple Activities/Fragments: Considered, not an option because not user friendly (in this case).
- Use ExpandableListView: Does not seem to be applicable to the data structure, the list of Bs and Cs should be visible from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

To implement this type of view you need to implement two things.

```
ListView listView;
IArrayAdapter iArrayAdapter;
```

Initialize listView with id provided in xml.

```
Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            iArrayAdapter = new IArrayAdapter(Activity.this,
                    R.layout.list_item, "list of items group it from Bean");
            listView.setAdapter(iArrayAdapter);
            iArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

list_item is another layout which contaion type of display you need to display in list.

IArrayAdapter is class extending ArrayAdapter

```
public class IArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<IBean> {

private final Activity context;
private final ArrayList<IBean> iBeans;
private int resourceId;

public InboxArrayAdapter(Activity context, int resourceId,
        ArrayList<IBean> iBeans) {
    super(context, resourceId, inboxBeans);
    this.context = context;
    this.iBeans = iBeans;
    this.resourceId = resourceId;
}

/*
 * TO update View
 * 
 * @see android.widget.ArrayAdapter#getView(int, android.view.View,
 * android.view.ViewGroup)
 */
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = layoutInflater.inflate(resourceId, null);

    final IBean iBean = iBeans.get(position);
    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.message);
    final TextView rowTxt = (TextView) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.senderName);
    final TextView rowTxt1 = (TextView) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.senderMessage);
    final TextView rowTxt2 = (TextView) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.senderTime);
    final CheckBox check = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.check);
    .....set text here.....
return rowView;
}
```

}

imageView, rowtext, etc are part of layout list_item

ANd IBean is java bean class contain your 5 iTem in a list.
Any item you don't want left it blank.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As far as I see, you are only using one ListView (that would be for the list of A objects in my question). But I have three cursors in total (for the list of A, B and C objects). Along your suggestion they would have to appear somewhere in the `getView()` method of the adapter and the adapter would have to implement `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>`. Right? Feels somehow wrong to me...

Comment: Here in thi line 
iArrayAdapter = new IArrayAdapter(Activity.this,
                    R.layout.list_item, "list of items group it from Bean"); i am passing array list of type Ibean as in your case class "A". For view part maxinum length of list of B or C you ned to provide in layout list_item.

I need to see about LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>.